# Dynamic default value date via combo box change

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have 1 Combo box and 1 Date textbox.
All I want is to create dynamic date textbox default value via combo box, for example when i choose BIKE SERVICE in combobox then date textbox default value will change to "Date()-Weekday(Date())+30" and if i choose others like CAR SERVICE it will change to "Date()-Weekday(Date())+180"

```
Private Sub Form_Load() If CBO_SERVICE = "BIKE SERVICE" Then
    TextDate.DefaultValue = "Date()-Weekday(Date())+30" End If End Sub

Private Sub CBO_SERVICE_Click() If CBO_SERVICE = "BIKE SERVICE" Then
    TextDate.DefaultValue = "Date()-Weekday(Date())+30" End If End Sub

Private Sub CBO_SERVICE_Dirty(Cancel As Integer) If CBO_SERVICE = "BIKE SERVICE" Then
    TextDate.DefaultValue = "Date()-Weekday(Date())+30" End If End Sub
```

Didn't show errors but Nothing happened hehe, please help

Comment: If this is Microsoft access, use the [ms-access] tag, not [access]

Comment: Done thanks, any suggest to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default value - which is a string - like this:

```
Me!TextDate.DefaultValue = "#" & Format(DateAdd("d", -Weekday(Date) + 30, Date), "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
```